# How do I find $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left [\left (1+\frac{2}{n^a}\right )^{-n^b}n^c\right ]$ for real $a,b,c$ and $n\geq 1$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Evaluate $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}\left [\left (1+\frac{2}{n^a}\right )^{-n^b}n^c\right ]$ for real $a,b,c$ and $n\geq 1$.

I am not sure how to do this but the hint given is to consider various cases of $a>b$, $a<b$, $a=b$ and $c>0$, $c<0$.

Comment: Is $n^c$ included in your expression?

Comment: @Qwerty Yes it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$t=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}\left (1+\frac{2}{n^a}\right )^{-n^b}n^c=\large \displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n^c}{e^\frac{2n^b}{n^a}}$$.

- If $b>a$ then $t=0$
- If $b< a$ then $t\to\infty$
- If $a=b$ and $c<0$ then $t=0$ but If $a=b$ and $c>0$ then $t\to\infty$

Answer (score 3):

Standard limit rule says$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left [\left (1+\frac{2}{n^a}\right )^{-n^b}\right]=e^{-2n^{b-a}}$$ 
So result is $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{n^c\over e^{2n^{b-a}}}$$

$b>a\implies\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{n^c\over e^{2n^{b-a}}}\to 0 \ \forall $ finite $c$

$b=a\implies \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{n^c\over e^{2n^{b-a}}} \to \infty\ \ $ if $c\gt 0$, $1$ if $c=0$ and $0$ if $c\lt 0$

$b<a \implies \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{n^c\over e^{2n^{b-a}}} \to \infty$

Comment: I think you still need to consider $c>0$ for the 2nd case $a=b$.

Comment: Well the limit doesn't really equal that expression.  We just know $\left(1+\frac{2}{n^a}\right)^{-n^b} \sim e^{-2n^{b-a}}$.  The argument should carry on similarly from there.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I think I have covered the case $a=b$ in more detail than anyone else..

Answer (score 1):

$$=\frac{n^c}{(1+\frac{2}{n^a})^{n^b}}$$
now let $$l=(1+\frac{2}{n^a})^{n^b}$$
$$\ln l={n^b}\ln({1+\frac{2}{n^a}})=\frac{2n^b}{n^a}\frac{\ln({1+\frac{2}{n^a}})}{2/n^{a}}=\frac{2n^b}{n^a}.1$$
$$\therefore l=e^ {\frac{2n^b}{n^a}}$$
therefore original limit is $$=\frac{n^c}{e^{2n^{b-a}}}$$ 
now exponential function raises a lot faster than a finite polynomial thus limit would $\infty$ if $b<=a$ and $0$ if $b>a$ assuming $c$ is positive

Comment: Doesn't that 4th $=$ sign need justification?

Comment: yes you are right , but i thought it's pretty standard as $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1$