# Evaluate $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}\left [\left (1+\frac{2}{n^a}\right )^{-n^b}n^c\right ]$ for real $a,b,c$ and $n\geq 1$.

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-explanation

Evaluate $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}\left [\left (1+\frac{2}{n^a}\right )^{-n^b}n^c\right ]$ for real $a,b,c$ and $n\geq 1$.

Which of the following are true?

(a) If $b<a$, $x\to 0$ as $n\to ∞$

(b) If $a < b$, $x\to 0$ as $n\to ∞$

(c) If $a = b$ and $c > 0, x \to ∞$ as $n \to ∞$

(d) If $a = b$ and $c < 0, x\to ∞$ as $n \to ∞$

I was stuck for a long time, with this problem. I searched this site, to find, whether this was previously asked or not (as I saw, duplicates are closed according to the site policy). I found a question asked some years ago. Here's the link:

[How do I find $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left [\left (1+\frac{2}{n^a}\right )^{-n^b}n^c\right ]$ for real $a,b,c$ and $n\geq 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1828152/how-do-i-find-lim-n-to-infty-left-left-1-frac2na-right-nbnc?noredirect=1)

I looked at all the answers. But, somehow I feel some informations are very much lacking in all the answer and the question as well. I was particularly interested in the answer of a user named Qwerty. I quote the answer hereby:

> Standard limit rule says$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left [\left (1+\frac{2}{n^a}\right )^{-n^b}\right]=e^{-2n^{b-a}}$$
> So result is $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{n^c\over e^{2n^{b-a}}}$$
>
> > $b>a\implies\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{n^c\over e^{2n^{b-a}}}\to 0 \ \forall $ finite $c$
> >
> > $b=a\implies \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{n^c\over e^{2n^{b-a}}} \to \infty\ \ $ if $c\gt 0$, $1$ if $c=0$ and $0$ if $c\lt 0$
> >
> > $b<a \implies \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{n^c\over e^{2n^{b-a}}} \to \infty$

This seems to be the most appealing to me. But I have a few questions (or to be definite, I am having a hard time with $3$ questions, regarding this question and the solution.):

- The user says :

> Standard limit rule says$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left [\left (1+\frac{2}{n^a}\right )^{-n^b}\right]=e^{-2n^{b-a}}$$
> So result is $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{n^c\over e^{2n^{b-a}}}.$$

Now, the thing is if this was a standard fact, it was completely unknown to me. I was searching for a proof of this result. To my surprise, in that link (above) , a user named, avz2611 posts a proof of this apparent new result. I quote his proof as well:

> $$=\frac{n^c}{(1+\frac{2}{n^a})^{n^b}}$$
> *now let $$l=(1+\frac{2}{n^a})^{n^b}$$
> $$\ln l={n^b}\ln({1+\frac{2}{n^a}})=\frac{2n^b}{n^a}\frac{\ln({1+\frac{2}{n^a}})}{2/n^{a}}=\frac{2n^b}{n^a}.1$$
> $$\therefore l=e^ {\frac{2n^b}{n^a}}$$
> therefore original limit is $$=\frac{n^c}{e^{2n^{b-a}}}$$*
> now exponential function raises a lot faster than a finite polynomial thus limit would $\infty$ if $b<=a$ and $0$ if $b>a$ assuming $c$ is positive.

I did a little modification as I used italics to highlight the proof of the above identity. Nevertheless, this proof, looks good **only if, we assume $a>0$ in the 4th step, which appears to be using the formula $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{ln(1+x)}{x}=1,$ and if, say, $a<0$, then in the 4th step, $$\frac{\ln({1+\frac{2}{n^a}})}{2/n^{a}}=1$$, is not true, as $\frac{2}{n^a}$ does not tend to (or approach) $0$ if, $a$ is negative, it rather tends to infinity. So, the assumption that should have been taken, is that $a>0$ in order to use the identity, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left [\left (1+\frac{2}{n^a}\right )^{-n^b}\right]=e^{-2n^{b-a}}$$ as in Qwerty's answer.**

It seems, each and every answer is making use of this identity. But I am not quite convinced about it's usage, unless it is done under the assumption, $a>0.$ *Am I missing something? Further, is this identity a very standard fact, that can be used as a theorem ?*

- My next question, is, how does , say, for example, in Qwerty's answer, how was it concluded, "$b>a\implies\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{n^c\over e^{2n^{b-a}}}\to 0 \ \forall $ finite $c$ " ? I got convinced by this statement, by *intuitively guessing maybe,* that, $e^{2n^{b-a}}$ increases more *rapidly* than, $n^c$, without no *reasoning so as to back up this intution*. My question, is, was this fact stated solely based on  *intuition ?*
- The next question, also is similar to the previous one. In the quoted answer, it is mentioned, "$b<a \implies \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{n^c\over e^{2n^{b-a}}} \to \infty$". Again, was this fact, solely stated based upon intuition and *appeals the reader to just convince themselves, that this indeed holds, by using intuitions* ?

These are the $3$ questions, that I am having a hard time dealing with. I am looking for an **elementary answer, to these questions, because, I don't seem to have an adequate knowledge in real analysis as of now. So, to be precise, an answer to these questions of mine, that uses only elementary calculus is the most optimal or better say, acceptable judging this scenario.**

*To be honest, I dont know, whether these sort of posts are allowed here or not. But I found that majority of users advocate for posts asking for clarifications for a particular solution, to be acceptable.*

Comment: (+1) As for your first question, you are absolutely right. Even more: writing an equality with a limit as $n\to\infty$ on the LHS, and a non constant expression (depending on $n$) on the RHS, is weird. There should be no limit on the LHS, and a $\sim$ instead of $=$ in the midde. Moreover, even like that and even if $a>0,$ the claim holds only if $b>2a.$

Comment: I think the problem of the three answers is not that they don't consider the case $a\leqslant 0$ when they are using $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\left (1+\frac{2}{n^a}\right )^{-n^b}n^c=\lim_{n\to \infty} e^{-2n^{b-a}}n^c$ (which is wrong, for example when $(a,b,c)=(-1,0,1)$). I think the problem of them is that they are using it. This is similar to the following common mistake : $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+0)^n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let analize all the cases, using that

$$\left (1+\frac{2}{n^a}\right )^{-n^b}n^c=n^ce^{-n^b \log \left (1+\frac{2}{n^a}\right ) }$$

**1. $b<a$**

- case $a\le 0$ with $u=-a\ge 0$ and $v=-b>u$

$$n^ce^{-n^b \log \left (1+\frac{2}{n^a}\right ) }=n^ce^{-n^{-v} \log \left (1+2n^u\right ) }\sim n^c$$

- case $a> 0$ and $b\le 0$ with $v=-b\ge 0$

$$n^ce^{-n^b \log \left (1+\frac{2}{n^a}\right ) }=n^ce^{-2n^{-v-a} \frac{\log \left (1+\frac{2}{n^a}\right )}{\frac{2}{n^a}} }\sim n^c$$

- case $0<b<a$

$$n^ce^{-n^b \log \left (1+\frac{2}{n^a}\right ) }=n^ce^{-2n^{b-a} \frac{\log \left (1+\frac{2}{n^a}\right )}{\frac{2}{n^a}} }\sim n^c$$

**2. $b>a$**

- case $b>a\ge 0$

$$n^ce^{-n^b \log \left (1+\frac{2}{n^a}\right ) }=n^ce^{-2n^{b-a} \frac{\log \left (1+\frac{2}{n^a}\right )}{\frac{2}{n^a}} }\to 0$$

- case $b \ge 0 > a$ with $u=-a>0$

$$n^ce^{-n^b \log \left (1+\frac{2}{n^a}\right ) }=n^ce^{-n^{b} \log \left (1+2n^u\right ) }\to 0$$

- case $a<b<0$ let $u=-a\ge 0$ and $v=-b>u$

$$n^ce^{-n^b \log \left (1+\frac{2}{n^a}\right ) }=n^ce^{-n^{-v} \log \left (1+2n^u\right ) }\sim n^c$$

**3. $a=b$ and $c>0$**

- case $a,b\ge 0$

$$n^ce^{-n^b \log \left (1+\frac{2}{n^a}\right ) }=n^ce^{-2 \frac{\log \left (1+\frac{2}{n^a}\right )}{\frac{2}{n^a}} }\to \infty$$

- case $a,b< 0$ with $u=-a>0$

$$n^ce^{-n^b \log \left (1+\frac{2}{n^a}\right ) }=n^ce^{-n^{-u} \log \left (1+2n^u\right ) }\to \infty$$

**4. $a=b$ and $c<0$**

- case $a,b\ge 0$

$$n^ce^{-n^b \log \left (1+\frac{2}{n^a}\right ) }=n^ce^{-2 \frac{\log \left (1+\frac{2}{n^a}\right )}{\frac{2}{n^a}} }\to 0$$

- case $a,b< 0$ with $u=-a>0$

$$n^ce^{-n^b \log \left (1+\frac{2}{n^a}\right ) }=n^ce^{-n^{-u} \log \left (1+2n^u\right ) }\to 0$$